# Observe objects created using JSON in Aurelia

Tags: json, typescript, treeview, aurelia

I have a tree structure shamelessly acquired from [building a treeview in aurelia](http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/building-a-treeview-in-aurelia)

This works great when I push nodes onto the tree. What I would like to do is parse a json object and push that onto the tree. This partly works, as the tree is rendered but I am unable to expand / collapse nodes that have children. I believe this is due to a call to hasChildren being a method and not a property and possibly deep binding. I have tried changing this method to a get property but don't seem to be able to get this to work.

**Node Model Class**

```
export class NodeModel {
    public name: string;
    public visible: boolean;
    public children: NodeModel[];
    public expanded: boolean;
    public icon: string;    

    constructor(name: string, children: NodeModel[])
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.children = children || [];
        this.visible = true;

        if (this.hasChildren()) {
            this.icon = "fa fa-chevron-down";
            this.expanded = true;
        }
    }

    hasChildren(): boolean {
        return this.children.length > 0;
    }

    toggleNode(): void {

        for (var i: number = 0; i < this.children.length; i++) {
            this.children[i].visible = !this.children[i].visible;
        }

        this.expanded = !this.expanded;

        if (this.expanded === true) {
            this.icon = "fa fa-chevron-down";
        } else {
            this.icon = "fa fa-chevron-right";
        }
    }
}
```

**Treeview VM**

```
import {NodeModel} from "node-model";

export class T {    
    private locations: NodeModel[];    

    constructor() {        
        this.locations = [];
        var texas = new NodeModel('Texas',
            [new NodeModel('Houston', []),
                new NodeModel('Austin', [])]);

        console.log(JSON.stringify(texas));

        this.locations = [texas];     
    }     

    addCardiff(): void {        
        var cardiff = new NodeModel('Cardiff',
            [new NodeModel('Cardiff Bay', [])]);
        this.locations.push(cardiff);
    }    

    addBristol(): void {
        var bristol = `{"name":"Bristol","children":
                        [{"name":"Easton","children":[],"visible":true},
                        {"name":"Eastville","children":[],"visible":true}],
                        "visible":true,"icon":"fa fa-chevron-down","expanded":true}`;

        var d = JSON.parse(bristol);
        this.locations.push(d);
    }
}
```

**Tree node component**

```
import {bindable} from 'aurelia-framework';

export class TreeNode {

    @bindable current = null;

}
```

**Tree node component view**

```
<template>
    <ul show.bind="current.visible" style="list-style-type: none;">
        <li>
            <div>
                <span if.bind="current.hasChildren()" click.trigger="current.toggleNode()" class="${current.icon}"></span>
                <span>${current.name}</span>
            </div>

            <tree-node repeat.for="node of current.children" current.bind="node"></tree-node>

        </li>
    </ul>
</template>
```

**view**

```
<template>    
    <require from="tree-node"></require>
    <tree-node repeat.for="node of locations" current.bind="node"></tree-node>
    <button click.trigger="addCardiff()" class="btn btn-default">Add Cardiff</button>         
    <button click.trigger="addBristol()" class="btn btn-default">Add Bristol</button>             
</template>
```

Output below

[image]

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Regards

Mike

Comment: Could you provide a gist that demonstrates your issue? You can use this https://gist.run/?id=c32f322b1f56e6f0a83679512247af7b a base

Comment: here is the Gist https://gist.run/?id=342be3fcf43c2d698dfefb95bdd9e9b2 doesn't run, probably because it's typescript.

Comment: tree-node webcomponent is missing. Could you provide that? Just copy and paste, don't worry if it is typescript

Comment: @FabioLuz, Thank you for the response. I have updated the gist now.

Answer (score 1):

The `addBristol()` method partially works because you are pushing a plain javascript object, not a `NodeModel` object. You have to convert the object and its children to a `NodeModel` object before pushing them onto the `locations` array. In this way, you will be able to call `hasChildren()`.

Comment: Are you suggesting that I use a reviver on the JSON.parse method?